# Media Manager connector | Private key issue

Tags: media-manager

[image: Media Manager exception while Loading Stubs folder]

I am facing private key related issue while clicking Stubs folder in tridion.

These are the steps i follwed.
1. Downloaded the certificate from the media manager URL provided - https://XXXX.sdlmedia.com
2. Installed it on CMS server as per ["SDL media manager documentation"](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Connector%20for%20Media%20Manager-v2/GUID-71A9BBA9-E89D-43D9-940F-463E02CAD145/)

3. Updated TridionSTS.xml signingsertificate,EncryptingCertificate value with the thumbprint values and media manager web service URL as below
4. Updated ServiceCertificate in Externalcontentlibrary.xml with thumbprint value of the certificate i installed.

After that I am loading stub folder in CMS but getting the exception message as below.
Server stack trace: 
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.HostSideAdapters.TridionUserViewToContractHostAdapter.GetSamlToken(String appliesTo, Byte[]& proofTokenBytes, DateTime& validFrom, DateTime& validTo, String& internalTokenReferenceAssertionId, String& externalTokenReferenceAssertionId)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.Contracts.ITridionUserContract.GetSamlToken(String appliesTo, Byte[]& proofTokenBytes, DateTime& validFrom, DateTime& validTo, String& internalTokenReferenceAssertionId, String& externalTokenReferenceAssertionId)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.AddInSideAdapters.TridionUserContractToViewAddInAdapter.GetSamlToken(String appliesTo, Byte[]& proofTokenBytes, DateTime& validFrom, DateTime& validTo, String& internalTokenReferenceAssertionId, String& externalTokenReferenceAssertionId)
   at SdlMediaManagerConnector.SdlMediaManagerContext.b__0(String key)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at SdlMediaManagerConnector.SdlMediaManagerContext.GetSecurityToken()
   at SdlMediaManagerConnector.SdlMediaManagerContext.get_MediaManagerClient()
   at SdlMediaManagerConnector.SdlMediaManagerContext.GetFolderContent(IEclUri parentFolderUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.AddInSideAdapters.ContentLibraryContextViewToContractAddInAdapter.GetFolderContent(IEclUriContract parentFolderUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypesContract itemTypes)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPyyc.png): 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.Contracts.IContentLibraryContextContract.GetFolderContent(IEclUriContract parentFolderUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypesContract itemTypes)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.HostSideAdapters.ContentLibraryContextContractToViewHostAdapter.GetFolderContent(IEclUri parentFolderUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.GetList(String parentItemId, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1 basedOnSchema)
   at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

If anyone has the Idea about this exception?

Comment: Have you checked access rights as outlined here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/sdl-media-manager-connector-with-cme-2013-sp1-no-valid-certificates/8175#8175 ?

Comment: @Raimond Thanks for the reply. I have  installed public certificate called *.sdlmedia.com  from https://xxxx.sdlmedia.com. If you can please let me know from where can I get private certificate?

Comment: You need to generate it. See also here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Connector%20for%20Media%20Manager-v2&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-E0AA3395-9EA0-4C73-B169-D59487BCD47B.xml&docid=GUID-E0AA3395-9EA0-4C73-B169-D59487BCD47B&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E0AA3395-9EA0-4C73-B169-D59487BCD47B

Comment: Thanks Raimond. It was due to public key of the self signed certificate I had generated was not installed on media manager system. I has been resolved now.